# Using a 7.4 V LiPo Battery for an Arduino Feather 32u4

Tags: arduino, voltage, batteries, battery-charging, lipo

I am working on an Arduino project at the moment, with the following board:

[Adafruit Feather 32u4](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-32u4-basic-proto/power-management)

And it says I need 3.7 V of LiPo to power it.

However I also have a valve that I want to open and close (with a relay that is controlled by the Feather) and that needs 7.4 V. So I considered buying a 7.4 V LiPo battery (like one for RC cars).

The question now is:

- Is there a way to use the 7.4 V Battery and only use 3.7 V for my Feather, while maintaining the full 7.4 V for my valve relay?
- And if so, how would I do that? (Would it also still be possible to charge the 7.4 V battery via the USB port of the Feather, as written in the description?)

I am an absolute beginner when it comes to electrical engineering.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a 7.4V Battery and a DC/DC converter (buck type) with 3.7V output voltage (Such a task is the main purpose of DC/DC converters).

Comment: Thanks I will check that out.